# Can't get Wireguard running on Freebsd to ping

Tags: freebsd, wireguard

I have a Freebsd installation running VirtualBox on my local LAN behind NAT trying to connect out to a Scaleway VPS running Ubuntu 20.04.

Using Debian 10 the VPN connects just find and I can ping all interfaces and ssh between machines.

But using Freebsd, I cannot ping the local wg0 interface. However wg show appears to show the VPN connecting. All firewalls on Freebsd are off, and of course I have configured only one Endpoint as I'm behind NAT.

I'm not knowledgeable with Freebsd, so there may be something I'm not doing.

```
# cat wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.40.1/24
ListenPort = 51440
PrivateKey = <stuff>

# wg-quick up ./wg0.conf
[#] wireguard-go wg0
INFO: (wg0) 2020/09/29 02:13:45 Starting wireguard-go version 0.0.20200320
[#] wg setconf wg0 /tmp/tmp.iIjG9fLd/sh-np.ozVBNl
[#] ifconfig wg0 inet 192.168.40.1/24 192.168.40.1 alias
[#] ifconfig wg0 mtu 1420
[#] ifconfig wg0 up
[+] Backgrounding route monitor
```

All looks fine to me...

```
# ifconfig -a inet
wg0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1420
options=80000<LINKSTATE>
inet 192.168.40.1 --> 192.168.40.1 netmask 0xffffff00
Opened by PID 28234
```

but when I try to ping I get no response

```
# ping 192.168.40.1
PING 192.168.40.1 (192.168.40.1): 56 data bytes
```

In FreeBSD would I expect a ping response?

I'm intentionally only showing one site.

Configuring the Peer makes no difference.

Thanks
John